# Flutter - get city name

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

How can I know the city name in flutter? I have used so many packages and only got the Lang and Lat
I want to get the city name !!
Is there any package that can help me with this issue?

```dart
import 'package:flutter_material_pickers/flutter_material_pickers.dart';
import 'package:random_color/random_color.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:geocoder/geocoder.dart';

class _ProfileScreenState extends State<ExploreScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  String cityName = ksaCities[29];
  double userLongitude;
  double userLatitude;
  int page = 0;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentLocation();
  }

  Future<Address> getCurrentLocation() async {
    LocationData myLocation;
    String error;
    Location location = new Location();
    try {
      myLocation = await location.getLocation();
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED') {
        error = 'please grant permission';
        print(error);
      }
      if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED_NEVER_ASK') {
        error = 'permission denied- please enable it from app settings';
        print(error);
      }
      myLocation = null;
    }
    final coordinates =
        new Coordinates(myLocation.latitude, myLocation.longitude);
    var addresses =
        await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
    var first = addresses.first;
    print(
        ' ${first.locality}, ${first.adminArea},${first.subLocality}, ${first.subAdminArea},${first.addressLine}, ${first.featureName},${first.thoroughfare}, ${first.subThoroughfare}');
    return first;
  }
}
```

Comment: which packages have you tried yet?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54761683/get-full-address-details-based-on-current-locations-latitude-and-longitude-in-f

Comment: This stackoverflow answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60911692/14219221

Comment: @Nuqo , I just have done as the example you put here in comments and it gives me this error :       [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method findAddressesFromCoordinates on channel github.com/aloisdeniel/geocoder)

Comment: @ Nuqo and this after that :            <asynchronous suspension>

Comment: update your question with code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get full address details based on current location's latitude and longitude in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54761683/get-full-address-details-based-on-current-locations-latitude-and-longitude-in-f)

Comment: @Nuqo , It gives me an error : Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(not_available, Empty, null, null)   and this error 
:           <asynchronous suspension>

Comment: check your google api key.is it proper also see this,
https://github.com/aloisdeniel/flutter_geocoder/issues/29

Answer (score 2):

Use [geocoder](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoder)
This help you to get current location(lat,lng,city,country name,address etc.)

```
import 'package:location/location.dart';
 import 'package:geocoder/geocoder.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

getUserLocation() async {

      LocationData myLocation;
      String error;
      Location location = new Location();
      try {
        myLocation = await location.getLocation();
      } on PlatformException catch (e) {
        if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED') {
          error = 'please grant permission';
          print(error);
        }
        if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED_NEVER_ASK') {
          error = 'permission denied- please enable it from app settings';
          print(error);
        }
        myLocation = null;
      }
      currentLocation = myLocation;
      final coordinates = new Coordinates(
          myLocation.latitude, myLocation.longitude);
      var addresses = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(
          coordinates);
      var first = addresses.first;
      print(' ${first.locality}, ${first.adminArea},${first.subLocality}, ${first.subAdminArea},${first.addressLine}, ${first.featureName},${first.thoroughfare}, ${first.subThoroughfare}');
      return first;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Gives me this error :                      [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method findAddressesFromCoordinates on channel github.com/aloisdeniel/geocoder)

Comment: and this after that :            <asynchronous suspension>

Comment: geocoder not working now , any other plugins ?

Comment: @btmme so you can use geocoding plugin, https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding